Are custom column headings in Searchkit results still a work in progress?
Customizing column heading labels in a Searchkit table display works in preview mode but not when the table is actually embedded in a form on a published page. The table does display but the headings revert to the actual column headings. Am I overlooking a step or a setting? I'm using WP 6.6.2 with Civi 5.78.3 with the default twentytwentyfour theme.

I think what's going on is you accidentally embedded the wrong table in the form.
Every Saved Search has an auto-generated display which uses all the defaults. That's the first one in the list when you create a form. After that will be the ones you made:

